# Padding automatically adjusting to screen sizes

Tags: css, responsive-design, breakpoints, bulma

I was wondering, is there a way, to just set kind of a default padding, which is will position an element, depending on the screen size automatically. For now I work with breakpoints, but I don't feel, like it's doing the perfect job:

```
@media (max-width: 1126px) {
    .navbar-item img {
        padding-left: 3.75rem;
    }   
}

// tablet / iphone6

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-item img {
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-burger.burger {
        padding-right: 30rem;

    }
}

@media (max-width: 320px){
    .navbar-burger.burger {
        padding-right: 23rem;

    }
}
```

I wish, that my logo and the burger would basically always be with a defined spase to the screen endings. So, for example, always 3rem, and if the screen size changes, the itemst take this space automatically. 
I work woth bulma, but somehow the containers do not solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: That's an awful lot of padding...and that's not a proper way to *position* elements. If you can demo the issue we can help futher.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: That's a huge rails app I am working on and it's for a company, so, I am afraid, I cannot post a code snippet here. But maybe you have kind of a tip or tutorial for me to solve this better.

Comment: Not without code. We don't need your *actual* code, just something that demonstrates the problem. Padding is not intended to position elements, just *size* them. Margin and other layout methods position elements....

Comment: The code above is the way I am trying to solve it, as it's not responsive and for every screen width I tried to define the position. Also trying with position absolute, etc.